# Cannot update or validate form data inside a bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

```js
$('.editimg').on('click',function(){
    $("#myModel").modal("show");
    var regionid = $(this).data('id');
    $(".modal-body #id").val( regionid );
    $("#region_id").val($(this).closest('tr').children()[1].textContent);
    $("#region_name").val($(this).closest('tr').children()[2].textContent);
    $("#description1").val($(this).closest('tr').children()[3].textContent);
    $("#description2").val($(this).closest('tr').children()[4].textContent); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="editimg" href="#" id="<?php echo $reg_id;?>"><img src="../dmo_images/action_ico/sys_icon_edit.png" width="20" height="20" alt="Edit"></a>
<div class="modal-body" >
  <form id="btnupdate" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form" >
    <table class="table" width="200" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr class="FormData" rowpos="1">
        <td class="CaptionTD">Name of Region</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="region_name" class="FormElement ui-widget-content" role="textbox" name="region_name" required=""></input></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="FormData" rowpos="2">
        <td class="CaptionTD">Description 1</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="description1" class="FormElement ui-widget-content" role="textbox" name="description1" required="" ></input></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="FormData" rowpos="3">
        <td class="CaptionTD">Description 2</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="description2" class="FormElement ui-widget-content" role="textbox" name="description2" required="" ></input></td>
      </tr>
    <tr class="FormData" rowpos="4"></tr>
  </table>
</form>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="submit" id="send" class="btn btn-danger" name="btnupdate" onClick="return validate_region()">Update</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
</div>
</div>
```

```
if(isset($_POST["btnupdate"]))
{
    $id=$_REQUEST["region_id"];
    $name=$_REQUEST["region_name"];
    $desc1=$_REQUEST["description1"];
    $desc2=$_REQUEST["description2"];
    
    $query1="Update tbl_region set region_name='$name', description1='$desc1', description2= '$desc2', created_date='$date' where region_id=$id";
}
```

//validation.js

```
function validate_region()
{   if(get("region_name").value=="")    {
        return false;       }
    else if(get("description1").value== "") {       
        return false;   }
    else if(get("description2").value== "") {       
        return false;   }
    else    {       
        return true;    }
}
```

I have a table with two image buttons at each row as below. 
[image: my table]

When these icons are clicked, I show a bootstrap modal with data in the row.
[image: my modal]
I've done the validation, but when I clicked on the "update" button, no validation is shown and the button doesn't work at all.

I am the very beginner level one so I don't know where do I wrong or left to code. I've been browsing online for solutions but I still can't get it. 
The updated value is needed to store in the database. 
**P.S** when click on delete button at Delete Modal, it also needs to delete from the database, which is not working too.

Your help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Where is the code for `validate_region()` function? And are you using ajax to update or delete the values from DB?

Comment: yet alone the php for this. Tagged as such with no supported code. And how we do we know if this isn't database-related?

Comment: After seeing your edit... well there you go, it is a db-related error, being unquoted values in `set region_name=$name, description1=$desc1` and checking for errors on the query would have told you about it.

Comment: Sorry I've changed it in my code, but I don't think it's the reason that update button is not working. I guessed it doesn't get any event...?  @Fred-ii-

Comment: either way, check for errors via PHP and MySQL and look at your developer console as well as your HTML source and `var_dump()` being extra tools.

Comment: validate_region() is just for checking null value. but I already add "required="" to the <input>", which is not appearing. @KinshukLahiri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following working code

```js
$('.editimg').on('click',function(){
      $("#myModel").modal("show");
      var regionid = $(this).data('id');
      $(".modal-body #id").val( regionid );
      $("#region_id").val($(this).closest('tr').children()[1].textContent);
      $("#region_name").val($(this).closest('tr').children()[2].textContent);
      $("#description1").val($(this).closest('tr').children()[3].textContent);
      $("#description2").val($(this).closest('tr').children()[4].textContent); 
  });

  function validate_region()
  {         
      if($("#region_name").val() == ""){
          return false;       }
      else if($("#description1").val() == "") {       
          return false;   }
      else if($("#description2").val() == "") {       
          return false;   }
      else   
      {       
          // HERE U SHOULD WRITE CODE TO WRITE IT TO DATABASE          
          $("#myModel").modal("hide");
          return true;    
      }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>sas</title>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  
</head> 
<body>

<div class='modal fade bs-example-modal-sm' id='myModel' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='gridSystemModalLabel'>
  <div class='modal-dialog modal-sm' style='transform: translate(0px, 50%);' role='document'>
      <div class='modal-content'>
          <form id="btnupdate" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form" >
          <div class="modal-body" >            
              <table class="table" width="200" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr class="FormData" rowpos="1">
                  <td class="CaptionTD">Name of Region</td>
                  <td>
                  <input type="hidden" id="region_id" class="FormElement ui-widget-content" role="textbox" name="region_id">  
                  <input type="text" id="region_name" class="FormElement ui-widget-content" role="textbox" name="region_name" required=""></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="FormData" rowpos="2">
                  <td class="CaptionTD">Description 1</td>
                  <td><input type="text" id="description1" class="FormElement ui-widget-content" role="textbox" name="description1" required="" ></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="FormData" rowpos="3">
                  <td class="CaptionTD">Description 2</td>
                  <td><input type="text" id="description2" class="FormElement ui-widget-content" role="textbox" name="description2" required="" ></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="FormData" rowpos="4"></tr>
              </table>
            
          </div>

          <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="reset" id="send" class="btn btn-danger" name="btnupdate" onClick="return validate_region()">Update</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          </div>
          </form>
      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
<table class="table">
  <tr>
      <th></th><th>Id</th><th>Name of Region</th><th>Description 1</th><th>Description 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td><a class="editimg" href="#" id="1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" style="font-size:20px"></i></a></td><td>1</td><td>val1</td><td>val2</td><td>val3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td><a class="editimg" href="#" id="2"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" style="font-size:20px"></a></td><td>11</td><td>val11</td><td>val21</td><td>val31</td>
  </tr>
</table>
  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please explain how this code answers the question. See [answer] for more information.

Comment: Oh thank you so much! Now it works for both blank data validation and updating into database! the modal hide/show works correctly too. Thank you. :-)) @Mohammed